# Почему такая иерархия наследования?

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Всем привет!

Есть такой код

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, mainloop
from vlc import Instance

URL = "https://str2.pcradio.ru/Eminem-med"


class Mp3Streaming(Tk, Instance):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        play_button = Button(self, text="Воспроизвести файл из интернета")
        play_button.pack()


def main():
    app = Mp3Streaming()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Выходит такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PyScripterProjects\Player\main.py", line 20, in <module>
main()
File "C:\PyScripterProjects\Player\main.py", line 16, in main
app.mainloop()
AttributeError: 'Instance' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

Я не могу понять почему метод mainloop ищется сначала в Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно вы думаете, он ищет сперва в Mp3Streaming потом в Tk и только потом в Instance и только потом не найдя этого метода нигде, выводит ошибку о том месте где он последний раз искал.

Comment: И как теперь быть?

Comment: Я хочу использовать множественное наследование

Comment: Вообще метод mainloop должен быть хотя бы у одного  базового класса правильно ведь?

Comment: @Александр да конечно. Так он в каком классе то?

Comment: В классе Tk есть mainloop

Comment: Это весь код примера? По возможности максимально покажите код, для восспроизведения проблемы

Comment: Да это весь код